# Firebase Storage - Get Download URL from Public Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have the logic of an image uploaded from the Frontend -> I get a download URL and attach it to the users document via a function.

This is the current code:

```
export const newProfilePictureUploaded = functions.region('europe-west1').storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

    if (!object.contentType?.startsWith('image/')) return;

    return admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket).file(object.name || '').makePublic().then(async data => {
        const filename = object.name as string;

        const splitName = filename.split('/');
        const folderName = splitName[0];

        if (folderName === 'profilePics') {
            const uid = splitName[1].substring(0, splitName[1].indexOf('.'));
            console.log(uid);
            await updateUserAvatar(uid, 'https://storage.googleapis.com/' + object.bucket + '/' + object.name)
            return;
        }

        console.log('No operation for folder ' + folderName);
        return
    })
})
```

Now the thing is the image is displayed on the URL, but even if the Image in the Storage Bucket is replaced, then URL still points to that old image. While it should be deleted and the new image should be in that path.

Why dont I use the `.getSignedUrl()` method? The URL I get back is too long specially for storing it in the RTDB, and the URL can be public so its really unoptimal for me to use that method.

Comment: A signed URL will fit just fine in Realtime Database.  It's not too long.

Comment: @DougStevenson I found out that they do not refresh content immediatly as well.

Comment: @DougStevenson went for a different solution now, gonna get the url on client side and send it to a callable cloud function which then updates the users profile image urls.